# Meu código SQL tá certo?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

Estou aprendendo SQL, e meu professor me deu uma atividade, eu fiz ela, mas ele me deu 1 de nota.
Eu quero saber se o código tá certo.
[image: Essa é a lista de atividades]

```
CREATE DATABASE escola;
USE escola;

CREATE TABLE aluno (
   codigo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nome VARCHAR (50) ,
   idade INT,
   cpf VARCHAR (15)
);

CREATE TABLE professor(
   codigo INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
   nome VARCHAR (50),
   disciplina VARCHAR (50),
   salario DOUBLE
);

INSERT INTO aluno
VALUES (0000000, 'Joao', 13, 01010101011),
(1111111, 'Maria', 18, 02020202020),
(2222222, 'Gabriel', 20, 03030303030),
(3333333, 'Marcos', 30, 04040404040),
(4444444, 'Vitoria', 16, 05050505050);

INSERT INTO professor
VALUES (00000, 'Victor', 'Matemática', 1500),
(01010, 'Joana', 'Português', 2500),
(02020, 'Mario', 'Geografia', 1800),
(03030, 'Daniel', ''Física, 2500),
(04040, 'Juliana', 'Arte', 2300);


UPDATE aluno SET idade = 19 WHERE nome='Maria'

UPDATE professor SET salario = 2300 WHERE nome='Joana'

DELETE FROM aluno WHERE nome='Marcos'

DELETE FROM professor WHERE nome='Juliana'


SELECT * FROM aluno

SELECT * FROM professor

SELECT * FROM aluno WHERE idade>16

SELECT * FROM professor WHERE salario>2000
```

Comment: Testaste o código?

Comment: Não sei se o instrutor considerou como erro, mas, os nomes do banco e das tabelas ele pediu em maiúscula. O INSERT está com vários erros, para inserir valores vc precisa apontar o campo que receberá tal valor, exemplo:  **INSERT INTO Aluno (codigo, nome, idade, cpf) VALUES (0000000, 'Joao', 13, '01010101011')**, vc inseriu os valores de cpf como sendo inteiro, mas, é um campo do tipo **VARCHAR**, por fim, na hora de inserir o valor `Física` vc não colocou dentro de aspas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que uma dica valiosa seja, evite ao maximo utilizar string quando for uma operação de "update" ou "delete". Porque se houver mais de um registro no banco com o mesmo valor exemplo "Maria" ou "Joana", vai acabar realizando a operação para todos. Sempre utilize o ID como referencia.

Exemplo: `UPDATE aluno SET idade = 19 WHERE id = 2`

E no insert que você fez ficou faltando aspas simples no valor **Fisica**.

```
INSERT INTO professor
VALUES (00000, 'Victor', 'Matemática', 1500),
(01010, 'Joana', 'Português', 2500),
(02020, 'Mario', 'Geografia', 1800),
(03030, 'Daniel', 'Física', 2500),
(04040, 'Juliana', 'Arte', 2300);
```